# How can I pass the state from parent component to a child to use in an API call?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a React app that queries an API that I built in Spring Boot. The React side should query the database to find a number of Activity objects to populate one Itinerary object. I want to keep track of the Ids of the activities so the app doesn’t return the same one more than once. Here’s how I set it up:

1. The Itinerary component has an array called "activities" in its state that will hold the ids. This starts out as empty. The Itinerary component also has a function called `UpdateActivities()` that updates the State with a new id when an activity is added.
2. `UpdateActivities` is passed as a callback to the child component Activity as props. The activities array in the state is turned into a string (because I'll be using this in the API call) and also passed as props to the `Activity` component.
3. In the `Activity` component, the callback function is further passed as a prop to the `ActivityDetails` component and the string of ids is further passed to `ActivityDetails` as well.
4. The `ActivityDetails` component makes the actual API call to my Spring Boot application and uses the callback function to update the State on the parent component. I attempted to save the string of ids to a constant to use in my API call. I want the string to go at the end of the call, so my app will know to skip over any activities with those Ids (currently hard-coded to 1).

The API call doesn't work if I replace 1 with the constant string of ids, because it shows up as empty. Is this an async issue? Is there a way to make it so the React app doesn't make the API call on `ActivityDetails` until the State is updated on the parent component?

> **Itinerary Component**

```
class Itinerary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      template: null,
      activities: []
    };
  }

  updateActivities = (id) => {
    const activityList = [...this.state.activities, id];
    this.setState({
      activities: activityList
    })
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    const {duration, travelerType, pace} = this.props.userAnswers;
    const transport = this.props.userAnswers.internalTravel.sort().join(', ');
    const TEMPLATES_URL = `http://localhost:8080/templates/duration/${duration}/travelers/${travelerType}/pace/${pace}/transport/${transport}`;
    axios.get(TEMPLATES_URL)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          template: response.data[0].content
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  }

  render() {
    let cities;
    if (this.state.template === null) {
      cities = <div><h3>Loading...</h3></div>;
    } else {
      let data = this.state.template.split(", ");
      cities = data.map((city, index) => {
        return (
          <section>

            <City
              key={index}
              day={index + 1}
              city={city}
            />
            <Activity
              key={`${city}${index}`}
              day={index + 1}
              lastDay={data.length}
              city={city}
              userAnswers={this.props.userAnswers}
              updateActivityState={this.updateActivities}
              activityList={this.state.activities.join(', ')}
            />
          </section>
        )
      });
    }


    return (
      <div>    

        <div className="row">

          <div className="col s9">
            <h3>{cities}</h3>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Itinerary;
```

> **Activity Component**

```
class Activity extends Component {

  render() {
    let city = this.props.city;

    if(this.props.day === 1) {
      return (
        <ActivityDetails
          userAnswers={this.props.userAnswers}
          city={city}
          timeOfDay="evening"
          handleActivityList={this.props.updateActivityState}
          activities={this.props.activityList}/>

      );
    } else if (this.props.day === this.props.lastDay) {
      return (
        <ActivityDetails
          userAnswers={this.props.userAnswers}
          city={city} timeOfDay="morning"
          handleActivityList={this.props.updateActivityState}
          activities={this.props.activityList} />
      );
    } else {
      return(
        <section>
          <ActivityDetails
            userAnswers={this.props.userAnswers}
            city={city}
            timeOfDay="morning"
            handleActivityList={this.props.updateActivityState}
            activities={this.props.activityList} />
          <ActivityDetails
            userAnswers={this.props.userAnswers}
            city={city}
            timeOfDay="afternoon"
            handleActivityList={this.props.updateActivityState}
            activities={this.props.activityList} />
          <ActivityDetails
            userAnswers={this.props.userAnswers}
            city={city}
            timeOfDay="evening"
            handleActivityList={this.props.updateActivityState}
            activities={this.props.activityList} />
        </section>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Activity;
```

> **ActivityDetails Component**

```
class ActivityDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activity: 'Loading...',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    const {travelParty, budget, pace, sites} = this.props.userAnswers;
    const cityTravel = this.props.userAnswers.cityTravel.sort().join(', ');
    const interests = this.props.userAnswers.interests.sort().join(', ');
    const entertainment = this.props.userAnswers.entertainment.sort().join(', ');

    const currentActivities = this.props.activities;
    console.log(`currentActivities: ${currentActivities}`);
    const city = this.props.city;
    const timeOfDay = this.props.timeOfDay;

    const ACTIVITY_URL = `http://localhost:8080/filter/${city}/${timeOfDay}/${travelParty}/${budget}/${pace}/${sites}/${cityTravel}/${interests}/${entertainment}/1`;
    console.log(ACTIVITY_URL);
    axios.get(ACTIVITY_URL)
      .then(response => {
        const newActivity = response.data.content;
        const updatedActivityId = response.data.id;
        this.props.handleActivityList(updatedActivityId);

        this.setState({
          activity: newActivity,
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
    }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.activity}</div>
    );
  }

}


export default ActivityDetails;
```

Revised with ComponentDidMount:

```
class ActivityDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activity: 'Loading...',
    };
  }

  getActivity() {
    const {travelParty, budget, pace, sites} = this.props.userAnswers;
    const cityTravel = this.props.userAnswers.cityTravel.sort().join(', ');
    const interests = this.props.userAnswers.interests.sort().join(', ');
    const entertainment = this.props.userAnswers.entertainment.sort().join(', ');

    const city = this.props.city;
    const timeOfDay = this.props.timeOfDay;

    const currentActivities = this.props.activities;
    console.log(`currentActivities: ${currentActivities}`);

    const ACTIVITY_URL = `http://localhost:8080/filter/${city}/${timeOfDay}/${travelParty}/${budget}/${pace}/${sites}/${cityTravel}/${interests}/${entertainment}/${currentActivities}`;
    console.log(ACTIVITY_URL);

    axios.get(ACTIVITY_URL)
    .then(response => {
      const newActivity = response.data.content;
      const updatedActivityId = response.data.id;
      this.props.handleActivityList(updatedActivityId);

      this.setState({activity: newActivity});
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getActivity();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.activities !== this.props.activities) {
      this.getActivity();
    }
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.activity}</div>
    );
  }

}


export default ActivityDetails;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The API call doesn't work if I replace 1 with the constant string of ids, because it shows up as empty. Is this an async issue?

This makes sense, yes. It's likely doing your `Itinerary`'s fetch at roughly the same time as your `ActivityDetails`' fetch, so the `state.activities` there is still an empty array (ergo empty string once you've mutated it and passed it down).

> Is there a way to make it so the React app doesn't make the API call on ActivityDetails until the State is updated on the parent component?

Yes, you can use other lifecycle methods to facilitate this. In your case, you probably want [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

You could do something like:

```js
class ActivityDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activity: 'Loading...',
    };
  }

  doMyGet(values) {
    const ACTIVITY_URL = `http://localhost:8080/filter/${city}/${timeOfDay}/${travelParty}/${budget}/${pace}/${sites}/${cityTravel}/${interests}/${entertainment}/1`;
    console.log(ACTIVITY_URL);
    axios.get(ACTIVITY_URL)
      .then(response => {
        const newActivity = response.data.content;
        const updatedActivityId = response.data.id;
        this.props.handleActivityList(updatedActivityId);

        this.setState({
          activity: newActivity,
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    const {travelParty, budget, pace, sites} = this.props.userAnswers;
    const cityTravel = this.props.userAnswers.cityTravel.sort().join(', ');
    const interests = this.props.userAnswers.interests.sort().join(', ');
    const entertainment = this.props.userAnswers.entertainment.sort().join(', ');

    const currentActivities = this.props.activities;
    console.log(`currentActivities: ${currentActivities}`);
    const city = this.props.city;
    const timeOfDay = this.props.timeOfDay;

    this.doMyGet(currentActivities)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.activities !== prevProps.activities) {
      this.doMyGet(this.props.activities)
    }
  }
  
  render () {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.activity}</div>
    );
  }

}


export default ActivityDetails;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried adding ComponentDidUpdate but I'm getting the same behavior (currentActivities returns as blank). I added the new code to my original question. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm realizing that your `Itinerary`'s `this.state.activities` *only* ever gets updated by calls from `ActivityDetails`. This means `this.state.activities` will always be blank the first time `ActivityDetails` calls for it. What is your expected behavior? How are activity IDs supposed to get to `Itinerary` initially?

Comment: The Activity details is what makes the API call with the parameters specifying what kind of activity it should get back. The Spring app sends a response based on this request, and I take the content of the response (which is the text of the activity) and set it on the state of ActivityDetail. The callback function handleActivityList() takes in the Id of that activity, and should pass it back up to the state of Itinerary to add it to the array of Ids.

Comment: Is this not the right way to do it? If I remove the last parameter from my API URL and adjust the Spring app so it's not expecting that param, then console.log() the state of Itinerary, I do see all of the ids in the array. But the way I have it up above the API call doesn't work at all because (I think) it's not getting the id before it makes the call.

Comment: That all makes sense. I'm not sure I understand your question. How are you expecting `ActivityDetails` to have access to any activityId *before* you've made a single API call?

Maybe I don't understand what you mean by `The API call doesn't work if I replace 1 with the constant string of ids`. Can you include the actual code?